# How to find a successive frequency from a series of frequencies

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, regression, music-theory

I am building a new instrument, and I need to find the sixth sequence in the given series,
{659.25, 440.00, 293.66, 196.00, 130.81}

that would be around 80 Hz.

An exponential regression at wa, gives the following function

$y(x)=987.76 e^{-0.404335 x}$

But I am not sure if this helps anything. The sixth frequency would be musically compatible with the other 5 frequencies, and its distance in Hz from the 5th, at 130.81 Hz is the unknown factor. How do I find this.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Each of those is about a fifth apart. You can use any one of the adjacent frequencies to get the ratio needed for the sixth frequency.

Comment: A fifth of the string frequency, or of the difference between two strings frqs.

Comment: It should be $87+\frac19=\frac{784}9 = 87.11$ or possibly $87-\frac7{81} = \frac{7040}{81} = 86.91$.

Comment: @Sompa I got 87.31. This is an equal temperament tuning so the factor is $2^{\frac{7}{12}}$.

Comment: Indeed @JohnDouma, even the OP's regression slope is $e^{-0.4043335} \approx 2/3$.

Comment: @Luthier A fifth is the interval. Intervals in music multiply so "difference" is misleading.

Comment: @JohnDouma you are correct, it is 87.31, an F2. Thank you!